# How do I write a function to convert a character vector into a character vector of unique pairs of its elements?

Tags: r, purrr, stringr

What the input would be:

```
c("a", "b", "c")
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

I want a function that returns:

```
[1] "a;b" "a;c" "b;c"
```

I need this function to work solely off its inputs. I've tried some stuff with `purrr::map()` and`purrr::reduce()`, but I haven't managed to get anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` from base R with `FUN` argument as `paste`

```
combn(x, 2, FUN = paste, collapse = ";")
#[1] "a;b" "a;c" "b;c"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: Perfect, didn't even know `combn()` existed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact result but maybe it might be useful:

```
test<-c("a", "b", "c")
lapply(test,function(x) paste0(x,";",setdiff(test,x)))
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a;b" "a;c"

[[2]]
[1] "b;a" "b;c"

[[3]]
[1] "c;a" "c;b"
```